# Oracle Advanced Queuing - ORA-38818 - illegal reference to editioned object

Tags: oracle, plsql, advanced-queuing

Seems like need some help on this one. I'm trying to build some queue table based on an object type as per the below script;

0.

```
...  
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbms_aq TO sch_utl  
/
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbms_aqadm TO sch_utl  
/
GRANT aq_administrator_role TO sch_utl  
/
BEGIN
  DBMS_AQADM.GRANT_SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE(privilege => 'MANAGE_ANY'
                                ,grantee => 'sch_utl'
                                ,admin_option => FALSE);

END;
/
```

1.

```
create or replace type o_utl_q_log as object
(/*some variables*/   

constructor function o_utl_q_log return self as result,  

member procedure queue_enqueue, 

static function queue_dequeue(p_wait number default 0)
  return o_utl_q_log,
);
```

2.

```
create or replace type body o_utl_q_log
(
  ...
);
```

Type and its's body compile with no errors, the problem occurs when;

3.

```
begin
  dbms_aqadm.create_queue_table( queue_table => 't_utl_q_log'
                            , queue_payload_type => 'o_utl_q_log'
                            , sort_list => 'PRIORITY,ENQ_TIME'
                            , storage_clause => 'tablespace TS_UTL_Q_TABLE_LOG'
                            , comment => 'Log queue table') ;
end;
```

I'm getting this err description;
ORA-38818: illegal reference to editioned object SCH_UTL.O_UTL_Q_LOG
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQADM", line 81
ORA-06512: at line 2
38818. 00000 -  "illegal reference to editioned object %s.%s"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to violate the rule "A noneditioned object
           may not depend on an editioned object."

Just in case, I'm working on XE 11g R2.

Many thanks to anyone for any help!

Answer (score 1):

By default, types are editionable.  Try:

```
create or replace noneditionable type o_utl_q_log as object...
```

instead of

```
create or replace type o_utl_q_log as object...
```

Comment: Matthew, thank you for your answer. Seems like this one is not working. I've tried to use the 'noneditionable' clause as per the below;

Comment: create or replace noneditionable type o_object_type as object(attr number) - but I'm getting ora-00922 missing or invalid option. Any other idea?

Comment: Ah... I see you are on 11g.  `NONEDITIONABLE` only works in 12c.  Sorry.  The only thing I can suggest that you try is to create the type under a brand new user -- one that does not have `EDITIONS` enabled.